# how to designate the working directory at run time in C++ in basis of cross platform?

Tags: c++, directory

I am confused how I can designate the working directory of "./" at run time.
So sometimes it will be the directory of the project file, sometimes it is the directory of the executable. All dependents how you execute the program.

How should I designate this working directory "./" as I want it always be? I mean I want to keep it always the directory of the executable for example.
And this implementation should be platform independent.(I think it will be rather big hard, so you can ignore this if it's not possible).

Comment: The problem is that not all platforms have filesystems.  There is no requirement for them to support filesystems.  Many embedded systems have no filesystems.  Also, there are filesystems that don't use the "../" notation and use other notations to separate files from folders.

Comment: What are you going to do with the directory? Storing data files in the program directory might not be allowed on all systems. Also, to be totally cross platform you cannot even assume the OS has directories.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ah, sorry, I didn't mean embedded system. Actually I just want to ask an implementation in both linux and win32 platform.

Comment: @BoPersson hi bo, I want to create codes with codes and I need to designate the working directory "./".  Or at least I should know where it is at run time.

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ cross platform framework".  Usually the frameworks have support for files and directories.  See also "c++ boost filesystem"

Answer (score 0):

If you have a compiler that supports the [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) Technical Specification or a `C++17` compiler you can use the new *soon-to-be* standard filesystem library

However I don't know of a catch-all way to discover the executable directory. One way that I think should work on `Windows` and `Linux` is to use `argv[0]` which contains the launch command and find its *canonical path*:

```
    std::error_code ec;

    // find the executable directory
    auto exe_folder = fs::canonical(fs::path(argv[0]), ec).parent_path();

    // set the current directory to the executable directory
    fs::current_path(exe_folder);
```

Currently `GCC v6` has *filesystem* as the Technical Specification otherwise you can also use `boost::filesystem` on-which it is based.

Typically programs don't have write permissions to the directory that contains the executable.

Comment: O.o c++17? thnx, it looks much cleaner than the solution I found.

Comment: This does not work with unicode, at least on Windows. If the path of the executable contains non-ascii character this will fail, as they are replaced with `?` in argv.

Answer (score 0):

myself found a solution if anyone else is interested. you have to have Qt on your computer at first.
you can change the working directory at run time with:
    QDir::setCurrent(qApp->applicationDirPath());

This will change the working directory at run time to that of the executable.

But it does not look very neat cause you have to have Qt.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've come up with (without requiring a C++17 compiler) is if you can guarantee a data-driven file is going to reside next to your executable, you can place a similarly named file in your project directory.

"./[your file].txt" is always going to exist, and you can use the content of these files as an indicator of where your current working directory is.